# Oracle 8: What client to use to connect from Windows 7 PCs?

Tags: windows, oracle, connection

I am here in an environment where there is a fairly old Oracle 8 (yes, eight) database installation and I need to connect to it from a fairly new Windows 7 installation.

What kind of client do you suggest to use to accomplish this?

First I tried Oracle SQL Developer (v4.0.2.15) but according to the [Oracle Community](https://community.oracle.com/thread/671137?tstart=0), Oracle 8 is not supported by SQL Developer anymore since v1.2. And I do indeed have problems connecting to it.

Thanks for any hints and suggestions (beside "upgrade the Oracle database!" ;-) )

**Solution:**

We luckily digged out an old Oracle 8i Client (version 8.1.7) and were able to connect successfully from Windows 7 (64bit) to the Oracle 8 database (version 8.0.5.0.0) using both SQL*Plus Worksheet and the ODBC driver. Hooray! **Thanks Justin & TenG for the hints!** Never thought that would work on a recent Windows version.

Comment: You probably can't (in a supported fashion) short of doing something like running a VM on your Windows 7 box that runs an older version of Oracle.  Exactly what version of Oracle are you trying to connect to (the 4 digit version)?  8.0.3 is very different from 8.1.7.4.  Do you have a support contract?  You're going to need a version of the Oracle client that is no longer available for download so that's going to involve asking support for old binaries.

Comment: It's 8.0.5.0.0. I have to investigate, if we have a support contract. I'm quite new in this environment.

Comment: Your best bet is probably Oracle client 8i/9i, using sqlplus. Oracle 8 came out when most folk still used sqlplus to do their work.

You can try (as I did from 10g to 8) use a bridging 11g database, talking to 8 via a db link and appropriate synonyms. Worked betwen 10g and 8, not sure it'll work 11g to 8.